# Missing Operator in query expression in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to run a query that returns letters before the space from an address column

```
SELECT col1,(Case When CHARINDEX(' ',address) = 0 then address Else LEFT(address,CHARINDEX(' ',address)-1) END) as streetNumber from table1
where stateID = 15
```

When I run this query in SQL Server Management Studio it runs but running it in Access gives me:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(Case WHEN
>   CHARINDEX(' ',address) =0 then address  Else LEFT(address,CHARINDEX('
>   ',address)-1) END)

But there are no operators missing. I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Access cannot handle CASE in query. Use IIf() or Switch() or Choose(). Also, CharIndex() probably isn't acknowledged either.

Comment: Access SQL is not the same as SQL Server SQL, so what you can do ini SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) has nothing to do with anything. Access has it's own variety of SQL, and you can't use features it doesn't support like `CASE` and `CHARINDEX`. You'll need to use the Access supported syntax instead. SSMS is only for SQL Server, and what SQL Server SQL supports has nothing to do with any other SQL variant.

Comment: ^What they wrote. If you want/need to use SQL Server syntax, you can use a **Pass-Through query** instead. The result will be read-only though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Access SQL and VBA:

```sql
Select 
    col1,
    IIf(InStr([address], ' ') = 0, [address], Left([address], InStr([address], ' ') - 1)) As streetNumber 
From 
    table1
Where 
    stateID = 15
```